# The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-1] but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, java-threads, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring WebFlux and the response of the asynchronous calls for different APIs works fine but I have the following issue when stopping the application:

```
2023-09-27 16:30:16.572[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:182)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:302)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:366)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.572[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.573[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.573[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.573[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.573[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-11] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.575[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-12] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.575[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-13] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.575[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-14] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.575[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-15] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-09-27 16:30:16.575[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m24696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(2)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-epoll-16] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
 app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

This creates a lot of threads to handle the request for my REST API.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class PapiController {

    @Autowired
    private WebClientService clientService;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/api")
    public Mono<String> queryApis(){
        return this.clientService.callApis();
    }
    
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class WebClientService {

    private final WebClient webClient1;
    private final WebClient webClient2;
    
    public WebClientService() {
        this.webClient1 = WebClient.create("https://pokeapi.co");
        this.webClient2 = WebClient.create("https://cataas.com");
    }
    
    public Mono<String> callApis(){
        Mono<String> pokemonResponse = this.callPokemonApi();
        Mono<String> catResponse = this.callCatApi();
        return Mono.zip(pokemonResponse, catResponse).map(tuple -> {
            String pokemon = tuple.getT1();
            String cat = tuple.getT2();
            
            String response = pokemon + "***" + cat;
            
            return response;
        });
    }
    
    private Mono<String> callPokemonApi(){
        return this.webClient1
                .get()
                .uri("/api/v2/pokemon/salamence")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
    
    private Mono<String> callCatApi(){
        return this.webClient2
                .get()
                .uri("/api/cats")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to close WebClient and the Threads correctly or something else is missing?

Comment: why do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency when you are using webflux?